# How do I redirect all requests to files in the root folder to point to another folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I've moved all of my files from the root of my website into a subfolder, I'd like to do an Apache redirect to point to the files without affecting the other subfolders in my site.

E.g.
/index.html -- redirect to --> /subfolder1/index.html
/file1.html -- redirect to --> /subfolder1/index.html

/subfolder2/index.html -- No redirect

Can anyone help me with the redirect rule that I need to write for this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be a start

`RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)$ /subfolder1/index.html [R]`

It says that any request with only one / in it, will be redirected, anything with two / will not match the rule, so will be passed over.